# How to store pdf file using nodeJS + multer + sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, multer

I'm using multer to save files to a temporary folder, I would like to know how to store this pdf file in the postgres database using sequelize.

Migration:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('testeUploads', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      fileDocumento: {
        type: Sequelize.BLOB
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('testeUploads');
  }
};
```

My model:

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const testeUpload = sequelize.define('testeUpload', {
    fileDocumento: DataTypes.BLOB
  }, {});
  testeUpload.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return testeUpload;
};
```

When using the create method, what should I pass to the fileDocument field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a Buffer object.
If you don't need to store the file on that temporary folder you can have the file in memory only and multer give you the file as a Buffer.

Docs:
[Multer Memory Storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#memorystorage)
[Sequelize Data Types](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/data-types.html) See BLOB

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const multer  = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post('/', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.file);
  // req.file.buffer is what you want to pass to create
});
```